# Foreign Key property won't set correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, foreign-keys, data-annotations

I have made an earlier post with similar code, and have updated the models to use a helper class instead of a ViewBag. It seemed to work like a charm until the database was updated.

These are my model classes.

```
[Table("Store")]
    public class Store
    {
        [Key]
        public int StoreId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    [Table("Purchase")]
    public class Purchase
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int StoreId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("StoreId")]
        public Store Store { get; set; }
    }

    public class PurchaseDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Store> Stores { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

        }
    }
```

```
public class PurchaseCreateHelper
    {
        public Purchase Purchase { get; set; }
        public List<Store> Stores { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My relevant part of the View for this question:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Purchase.StoreId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Purchase.StoreId, new SelectList(Model.Stores.Select( x => new { StoreId = x.StoreId, DisplayName = x.Name.ToString() + " - " + x.Address.ToString()}), "StoreId", "DisplayName"), new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Purchase.StoreId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the relevant part of my controller:

```
        // GET: Purchases/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var purchaseHelper = new PurchaseCreateHelper()
            {
                Stores = db.Stores.ToList(),
                Purchase = new Purchase()
            };

            return View(purchaseHelper);
        }

        // POST: Purchases/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(Purchase purchase)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Purchases.Add(purchase);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(purchase);
        }
```

When my code comes to db.Purchases.Add(purchase) the Store property of the purchase object is set to null. The StoreId however seems to be perfectly fine. I don't get why the Store object won't change with the StoreId property as I have annotated it with [ForeignKey("StoreId")]. Where did I mess up the connection between StoreId and Store?

UPDATE #2

```
        // GET: Purchases
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Purchases.ToList());
        }
```

```
@model IEnumerable<BookKeeper.Models.Purchase>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Store.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Type)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => (item.Store.Name))
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

UPDATE #3
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sE91.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you don't see any value for the purchase.Store, that's because the model binder only bind the StoreId (when request is sent from Browser to Web Server) which you specified in

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Purchase.StoreId, new SelectList(Model.Stores.Select( x => new { StoreId = x.StoreId, DisplayName = x.Name.ToString() + " - " + x.Address.ToString()}), "StoreId", "DisplayName"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The populating of purchase.Store belongs to EF. EF will load that Store when you do

```
dbContext.Purchases.Include(x => x.Store).FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == 1234);
```

UPDATE:

If you want the Store object in POST action

```
    // POST: Purchases/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Purchase purchase)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Purchases.Add(purchase);
            db.SaveChanges();
            purchase = dbContext.Purchases.Include(x => x.Store).FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == purchase.ID); // Not sure why you need Store information at this step.
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(purchase);
    }
```

Comment: In which class do I have to add this code? In the PurchaseDBContext?

Comment: In your example, you got 2 actions GET and POST. Which one you have the problem?

Comment: The post one, adding in the code in the post method doesn't seem to resolve the problem.

Comment: I added the code to your POST action. But still, I don't understand why you need that Store data when redirecting to Index page.

Comment: Store remains null, thus displaying no storename in the Index page.

Comment: Ok, haha, so the problem is your index page doesnt show store. You need to show your index view and controller. But before that, can you confirm the StoreID is saved successfully to database?

Comment: Added a picture of the database (only used 1 entry for the StoreId to test this time). However I know that the others were added correctly as well. The Store however remains null. So I assume there's an error somewhere in the foreign key.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see your added picture

Comment: Are they visible now?

Comment: You need to add Include() in your loading like this

            "return View(db.Purchases.Include(x => x.Store).ToList());"

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you for your patience with me.

Comment: And this is my best help so far in Stackoverflow. Really happy that my help solves your problem.